How to check if a container image is signed in Openshift?
I have an openshift cluster. I have an image which I know is not signed. I want to check whether if an image is signed or not manually? Is there a command for this? I tried commands like these:
podman trust inspect <image_name>
skopeo inspect docker-daemon:myimage:latest
Is there a way to do this? Once I do this I want to check it in my cluster as well but this is second step? How can I do this for just one image?

You can configure openshift to require signatures from certain repositories, see e.g. the documentation or this article.
There's no "check if an image is signed" feature in openshift; the above will cause openshift to reject unsigned images.
You can use Skopeo to verify the signature on individual images as described in this article. Alternatively, you can []configure a trust policy in Podman](https://access.redhat.com/articles/3116561) and attempt to run an image.

So, I have followed the butane to machineConfig from the original documentation and had a glance on the article you mentioned. My issue is that my OCP is dissconnected and has imageContentSourcePolicy that directs the registries configuration (default) to direct mirrors to my on-prem nexus instead of redhat.io, quey.io, etc. I have done the signature policy.json in a lab environment and when I do specify my mirrors in either ICSP or MC the policy is overwritten to insecure everything. Any insights?
